# Eclipse (CDT) project defaults

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How to change Eclipse project defaults?

I'm interested in CDT (C++ plugin) in particular, but I suppose that it isn't that differs from JDT. I want to get some custom compiler keys and Build options (like “Build on resource save” in C/C++ Build — Behaviour in C++ project properties) for each new project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100 percent to understand what you want.

If you want to automatically build the projects after the saving the source code file of c/c++ project in CDT. You can check the option in below screen shot,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is only one particular case and I asked for more. You know Project Properties menu. There are lots of options there. E.g. compiler options. Imagine I want every new project to be build with -pedantic compiler option without need to add this option manually for every project. So I want it to be by default. How could I gain this?